# Value of optional type 'UIColor?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIColor'

Tags: swift, syntax-error, option-type

Using

```swift
self.backgroundColor = .init(named: "my-color")
```

where `self` is an `UIView`, triggers this error:

> Value of optional type 'UIColor?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIColor'
> Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil' [Fix]
> Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil' [Fix]

The compiler knows that the `backgroundColor` property is of type `UIColor?`, so it should infer it for the initializer, right?

Moreover, knowing that the property is optional, the error message doesn't make too much sense for me.

Also, both auto fixes are "recursive", meaning that they don't fix the error, and I can apply them over and over again.

*Note: I know that I can use `UIColor.init` or simply `UIColor`. This is just a simplified example.*

Comment: Your code seems to be missing some context: you haven't included anything to show us what the definition of `self.backgroundColor` actually is.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: To me it's clear from the description that backgroundColor is of type `UIColor?`. I ran the code myself and could verify the same result as observed in this question and I still think it's a valid and intriguing question. It seems there's something about the way the swift semantic analizer is trying to infer the types.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, Right, but it's very clear to everybody that `self` is an `UIView`. But even without this, it's irrelevant, since I said that it's a property of type `UIColor?`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this error doesn't make sense and, after some research, I found it's actually a known bug in Swift. The reference is [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13815).
Basically, it seems the compiler tries to look through the optional to find your initializer.
It seems the fix will be shipped with the next release.

Comment: Is this still not fixed?

Comment: @Linus I've just tested it and it works - no compiler errors. How is it on your end?

Comment: No, not on my end at least. Do you mind posting some code?

Comment: I used that exact code as in the question. Can you tell what version of Swift are you using?

Comment: Swift 5 according to my build settings. You?

Comment: I'm on version 5.6 at this moment. Are you able to get it updated to the latest version? It seems you need at least version 5.4 where they released that fix: https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/65db86ba034403f33d784a0cd88b9628c8e46ffd

Answer (score 4):

`backgroundColor` is declared as optional. The compiler infers `UIColor?` and tries to create

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor?.init(named: "my-color")
```

which is not supported – and which is not related to the optional `init` method.

---

You must use the *non-optional* type

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "my-color")
```